# How to type characters in an interval?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a program which will type a line of text in 5 second interval. Now, what I am trying to do is to add function which will type the text character by character with small spaces between each character. I am trying to use Thread.Sleep but I my program crashes, and I'm not sure why.

How to do this properly?

```
    private void Interval(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbPause.Checked == false)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(txtText.Text + "{enter}");

            if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbInterval) tmrInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString());
            if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbRange) tmrInterval.Interval = random.Next(int.Parse(nudMin.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nudMax.Value.ToString()));
        }
        else if (cbPause.Checked == true)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            foreach (char character in charList)
            {
                SendKeys.Send(character.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
        }
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtText.TextLength < 1 || txtText.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "You must type text to proceed!";
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char character in txtText.Text)
            {
                charList.Add(character);
            }

            if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbInterval)
            {
                tmrDelay.Enabled = true;

                txtText.Enabled = false;
                nudInterval.Enabled = false;
                nudMin.Enabled = false;
                nudMax.Enabled = false;
                btnStart.Enabled = false;
                btnStop.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (tbType.SelectedTab == tbRange)
            {
                tmrDelay.Enabled = true;
                tbType.Enabled = false;
                txtText.Enabled = false;
                nudInterval.Enabled = false;
                nudMin.Enabled = false;
                nudMax.Enabled = false;
                btnStart.Enabled = false;
                btnStop.Enabled = true;
            }

            lblMessage.Text = "Starting auto typing in: 3";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code tip: If you find yourself doing `if(x == true) { /* ... */ } else if(x == false) { /* ... */ }` then you're probably meaning `if(x) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the exception you're getting?

Comment: @minitech, none at all, it just hangs until I log out of remote machine...

Comment: So it doesn't crash? Hm... when it hangs, try pausing it - which line of code is it stopped on?

Comment: @minitech, It doesn't stop. It just hangs, and since I am using remote desktop my whole remote desktop stops and only way to unhook is to log out and log back in which stops the debugging.

Comment: No, when it hangs, use the debugger's Pause function and see which line it's stopped on.

Comment: @minitech, It locks by screen completely, cannot click anything.

Comment: You're claiming this code locks the debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx), this is going to hang your GUI thread.

What I would do, is use a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx), and every [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx), have it type the next character.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer;
    string str;
    int char_num;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(str.Substring(char_num++, 1));
        if (char_num == str.Length)
            timer.Stop();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        str = "Jonathon";
        char_num = 0;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Note: If it's not obvious, this code requires a form with a `textBox1` and a button who's `Click` event is wired to `button1_Click()`.

If you want the first character to be sent right away, you can "cheat" by calling the `Tick` handler right away when you start the timer, by adding the following line:

```
timer_Tick(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: I have tried this but I couldn't figure out how to do this as I explained in another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764338/how-to-run-timer-inside-of-timer).

Comment: Well, I do get somewhat the idea of how to use timer. It's just I am using 2 timers already and I have had problems with using another timer with 2 already in place.

Comment: You can have all the timers you want, I'm not sure what the problem may be.

Comment: Ok, using sub string rather than array list seems to work. But in place in line: `SendKeys.Send(txtText.Text.Substring(b++, 1));` I am getting an error daying: `Index and length must refer to a location within the string.` in a second run of the timer.
Parameter name: length

Comment: What is the meaning of 1 by the end of the line?

Comment: I forgot a couple lines in the Tick handler. You need to stop the timer when the string is finished.

Comment: Also, the 1 means a length of 1. I only want one character from the string at a time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx